# Android Knowing whether a File is a file(.jpg, etc) or a folder AND compressing a file(.png, etc) and a folder

Tags: android, file, compression, zip, directory

I'm currently creating a program that compresses a file by using java.util.zip package. It works well but I noticed that compressing a folder/directory is different from compressing a file (correct me if I'm wrong). In my program, I have to know whether a selected file is a folder or a file(such as .jpg, .png, .apk and etc). I've tried some experiments for me to be able to know and here is the sample code in my filechooser activity : 
(currentDir is a File)

```
    if(currentDir.isDirectory())Toast.makeText(this,"Directory",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(currentDir.isFile())Toast.makeText(this, "File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

After inserting this, every file the I've chose in my activity outputs a "Directory" and not a "File" even though i chose an image. Can someone please help me on how to know whether a File in android is a folder or not? Thanks! (First Problem)

And as I have said earlier, I noticed that compressing a folder is different from compressing a file (correct/teach me if I'm wrong). I'm already done when it comes to compressing a folder but when it comes to compressing a file, such as images and etc, it still compresses the directory but I believe MUST compress only the file I've chosen. here is my sample code. (Second Problem)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(new File(currentDir.getPath()+".zip")) );
        zip( currentDir, currentDir, zos );
        zos.close();    
        Toast.makeText(this, "File successfully compressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
}

private static final void zip(File directory, File base,ZipOutputStream zos) throws IOException {
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = files.length; i < n; i++) {
      if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
        zip(files[i], base, zos);
      } else {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[i].getPath().substring(base.getPath().length() + 1));
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        while (-1 != (read = in.read(buffer))) {
          zos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

Any comments, help, suggestions, reactions is needed and will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void createZipFile(String path) {
        File dir = new File(path);
        String[] list = dir.list();
        String name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"), path.length());
        String _path;

        if(!dir.canRead() || !dir.canWrite())
            return;

        int len = list.length;

        if(path.charAt(path.length() -1) != '/')
            _path = path + "/";
        else
            _path = path;

        try {
            ZipOutputStream zip_out = new ZipOutputStream(
                                      new BufferedOutputStream(
                                      new FileOutputStream(_path + name + ".zip"), BUFFER));

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                zip_folder(new File(_path + list[i]), zip_out);

            zip_out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("File not found", e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

try with this code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm currently trying this code. But I don't know how did you declare 'BUFFER' and the method 'zip_folder' is missing. will you also provide it too? Thanks a lot.